# PHp - submit page returns Internal Server Error

Tags: php, html, css, authentication, flat-file

I'm making a flat file login system and when I click the submit the button on the login.php page it goes to protected.php and returns Internal Server Error, but when I just load the protected.php page without using the form everything turns out fine.

login.php

```
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <body>
        <center><img src="logo.png"></center>
        <div id="login">
            <form action="protected.php" method="post">
            </br>
            Username  <input type="text" name="user" class="text"/>
            <p></p>
            Password <input type="password"" name="pass" class="text" />
            <p></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="button">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

protected.php

```
<?php
$usr = "admin";
$pass = "admin";

$iusr = $_POST["user"];
$ipass = $_POST["pass"];

if ($iuser !== $usr || $ipass !== $ipass) {
?>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "login.php"
//-->
</script>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The funny thing about errors is that they usually come with some sort of message. Check your error log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Internal Server Error" could mean several things, but most likely means an error in your PHP code. This will require setting the `display_errors` property to "1" in your php.ini. The problem might also be a startup error, so you may wish to also consider the `display_startup_errors` property.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Two comments about the code, unrelated to your question: 1) the expression `$ipass !== $ipass` seems like a typo, as it will always return `FALSE`, and 2) this "security" is easily bypassed by turning javascript off. Consider using `header()` for redirects instead.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

**EDIT:** ... in this specific case, the error is use of the variable `$iuser`, which is undefined. You'd previously declared it as `$iusr`. Turning on error reporting or looking at the log will present you with good error messages to find these sorts of problems easily.

Answer (score 1):

login.php

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>
    <center><img src="logo.png"></center>
    <div id="login">
        <form action="protected.php" method="POST">
        </br>
        Username  <input type="text" name="user" class="text"/>
        <p></p>
        Password <input type="password"" name="password" class="text" />
        <p></p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="button">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

protected.php

```
<?php
$usr = "admin";
$pass = "admin";

$iusr = $_POST["user"];
$ipass = $_POST["password"];
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
if ($iusr != $usr || $ipass != $pass) {
?>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.location = "login.php"

</script>
</html>
<?php
}}
?>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `protected.php` file you have written a wrong condition your code has `($iuser !== $usr`  it should be `if ($iusr !== $usr || $ipass !== $pass) {`  also condition `$ipass !== $ipass`  should be like `$ipass !== $pass` below is the updated protected.php file

```
<?php
$usr = "admin";
$pass = "admin";

$iusr = $_POST["user"];
$ipass = $_POST["pass"];

if ($iusr !== $usr || $ipass !== $pass) {
    ?>
    <html>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location = "login.php"
        </script>
    </html>
    <?php
}
?>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <body>
        Login success
    </body>
</html>
```